# Howto manage website and user permissions with apache on Mac os X

Tags: mac, permissions, apache-http-server

I have lots of different websites in a Development directory in my home dir.

While developing, files get saved under my username but websites configured under apache it's permission need to be set as _www user and group.

What's the best way to handle this?

- Do I run apache under a different user/group?
- Do I run my development tools under a different user?
- Do add myself to the _www group? (seems like it doesn't work btw)

I've just switched to a mac and I'm trying to find a smooth development workflow, so it would be best if i could just run the necessary tools, save some files and be able to test the website without much hassle.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Who actually owns the files isn't important.

You just need to make sure that Apache's user/group have sufficient (most likely just read) [permissions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_permissions#Traditional_Unix_permissions). If you allow *all users* to read your web site data, it should work.

Use the *Get Info* dialog of the `Sites` directory to change permissions for *Everyone*. You also need to make sure *Everyone* has *Execute* permissions for your home directory (so they can enter, but not list). Also, `Sites` in your home directory might not work with FileVault (at least in my experience).